# Charged particle/cosmic ray track on sunglasses

Tags: particle-physics, polarization

I left my (polarized) sunglasses on car dashboard .. .
Returned, and immediately noticed a strongly lightened, partially dotted streak across entire left lens, cutting diagonally from "northwest" to "southeast". The streak or trail then directly picks up on the right lens, cutting across a small section of the "southwest" corner.

Is the cause more likely a high-energy/charged particle from the sun, or a cosmic ray originating outside the solar system?

If a cosmic ray, did it continue on and go right through the car, the parking lot, and the planet?

Comment: No, you scratched them but only noticed when you placed them at a certain angle to the light

Comment: Could you add the image?

Comment: Oh, the guilt, when you scratch your glasses... it's OK, that's not cosmic rays at work but thermodynamics. Unscratched glasses have a higher degree of order than scratched glasses, so all natural processes will try to scratch your glasses all of the time. You would have to expend an infinite amount of energy to keep them scratch free. ;-)

Comment: Kyle, sorry but I don't have the technolgy (or the skills) to post images.

Comment: Are they photochromic (variable tint) sunglasses?  Did the light streak disappear after a while?

Comment: Ernie,  No, the streak is indelible and exactly as it was ... (The 'glasses' are just clip-on shades from Target that I put on my old, empty prescription eyeglass frame, unneeded since cataract surgery).

Comment: If there are cosmic rays that can leave marks on your glasses then we are all in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

An examination of the lens under a bright light will provide the answer: if you see shadows, then the surface has been damaged, an indication of a scratch or abrasion, or of the deposit of some foreign substance.

A gentle washing of the surface of the lens, followed by a gentle drying, should remove debris, after which a repeat examination under the bright light should confirm the earlier conclusion.

If there the surfaces (inner and outer) are free of damage, then we will have to delve further into the matter.

Comment: Peter, there is no scratch or abrasion ... Have washed and dried them several times, there is no foreign matter to remove. The damage appears to be "inside" the plastic itself.

Comment: Next step is examination under a 10x loupe, prhaps followed by sectioning, though a careful examination of the other lense should be conducted first.  Science begins with careful examination and record keeping.